# Install ubuntu on kvm in console

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kvm

I use the following command to install Ubuntu server on KVM in a remote server using SSH console. But it  seems that it does not recognize the iso image I provided as (a) it does not install without network configuration (b) with internet access, it downloads everything from internet.

What is the right command for this purpose?

```
virt-install --name ubuntu1 --ram 4096 --disk \
path=/home/abc/images/MyLinuxServer.img,size=10,format=qcow2,size=10,bus=virtio \
--network network:kvmbr1,model=virtio --os-type=linux --os-variant=ubuntutrusty \
--nographics --location /home/abc/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso \ 
--extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you've shown in your answer only creates the virtual machine which isn't really relevant to the actual question - installing without a network.

If you've got the [correct ISO](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso) image then you can cancel the network configuration option and the option to download updates and the installer should continue.

Comment: How to cancel the option to download updates?

Comment: Have you downloaded the correct ISO?  I've just downloaded an ISO and installed it using a very similar (but not identical) command to the one you gave above. During the network config, I cancelled the auto-detection and then chose `Do not configure network at this time`. With no network configured, it didn't ask me about updates.

Comment: It seems that I'm doing something wrong because I've downloaded the  iso again form here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server and tried to install ubuntu on bare metal using USB. I still could not skip the networking step. It keeps asking me about the finding archive mirrors for downloading release information!

Comment: Others faced this problem too http://serverfault.com/questions/593115/ubuntu-server-14-04-trusty-tahr-installer-requires-internet-access-to-install

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a link to the ISO that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and mount he `.iso` on a directory and use it. Just remember to use the option loop to do so.

`mount -o loop /home/abc/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso /destination/path`

Comment: This didn't work: mount -o loop /home/abc/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso /mnt/cdrom and then replace --location with /mnt/cdrom . Still does not let met to install without network configuration